# kubectl losing connection to minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am using

```
*$ minikube version
minikube version: v0.28.2
```

and

```
*$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.3", GitCommit:"a4529464e4629c21224b3d52edfe0ea91b072862", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-09-09T18:02:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:44:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I am running a local cluster, while all of the sudden communication between the cluster and `kubectl` gets lost:

```
*$ kubectl get pods
No resources found.
Error from server (Timeout): the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get pods)
```

The problem goes away after performing an explicit `minikube stop && minikube start`

Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: What did you use to setup minikube? Where is it running? laptop? Is it running Virtualbox? Vmware?

Comment: 1. Followed the official instructions here to install: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases 2. On my laptop running `Ubuntu 16.04.5` 3. Virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to be a problem with your `kubectl` version.

When I have a server version too old, I usually download a kubectl of the same version.

Here the link (linux version):

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.10.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem had to do with resources.

Resolved by stopping `minikube` and then starting it like this:

```
minikube --memory 8192 --cpus 2 start
```

This [thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/567) was helpful.